# App Engine editing an instance in a repeated KeyProperty via the instance itself

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

Lets say I have the following models:

```
class Author(ndb.Model)
    books = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Book', repeated=True)

class Book(ndb.Model)
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
```

So at a certain point you'll have an author with a list of `n` books.

**Questions**:
When I'm editing a book how do I change the author without a reference to the 'current' author? Do I need to add a reverse relation with a `KeyProperty` on `Book`?

When changing the author I have to remove the book from the old author's list and add it to the new one. That feels kind of cumbersome. Is there a better way?

**Bonus question**: What if a book gets deleted? There will be a `None` value in the author's books list. Do I have to remove that?

**Note**: I'm using a repeated KeyProperty because this makes ordering the books easy, which in my case is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I'm editing a book how do I change the author without a reference to the 'current' author?

you can use `ndb.Model.allocate_ids` to reserve a key before the entity is saved

> Do I need to add a reverse relation with a KeyProperty on Book?

Given your model, the addition of a reverse lookup key can make your life easier

> What if a book gets deleted? There will be a None value in the author's books list. Do I have to remove that?

The key in `Auther.books` will not automatically becomes null in this case. You have to remove it yourself.

> I'm using a repeated KeyProperty because this makes ordering the books easy, which in my case is important.

A potential problem is that an entity has a size limit of 1mb. If an author is very prolific writer (e.g. Edwy Searles Brooks has 800+ published works), it can exceed the limit.

I would design the model this way:

```
class Author(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

class Book(ndb.Model):
    authors = ndb.KeyProperty('Author', required=True)  # Usually it is at most a couple of authors  
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
```

To find out all books written by a particular author with id 1234, you can

```
  Book.query(Book.authors == ndb.Key('Author', 1234)).fetch()
```

Apparently the ordering of books must be stored explicitly, I would suggest a third entity to keep track of this information:

```
class BookList(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
  book_keys = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Book', repeated=True)
```

Then you can retrieve books in this manner

```
stephen_king_book_list = stephen_king_book_list_key.get()
books = ndb.get_multi(stephen_king_book_list.book_keys)
# Some of key can lead to None if the underlying book is already deleted
# You can define some background job to sweep clean the list from time to time 
# But let filter out the bad guys first 
books = [b for b in books if b]
```

If you think your lists are going to be very very long, you can break a list down into segments like a linked list structure

```
class BookList(ndb.Model):
  prev_segment = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='BookList', required=False)
  next_segment = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='BookList', required=False)
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
  book_keys = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Book', repeated=True)
```

You can find the fist segment easily by:

```
  starting_point = BookList.query(BookList.name == 'Stephen_King',
     BookList.prev_segment == None
  ).fetch()
```

Of course if insertion is very frequent, you might want to use an alternative structure to hold the book list

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe my Book/Author example isn't the best for my use case. As stated, order is pretty important. Think of it as a Presentation/Slide relation. 
I prefer your design suggestion as well, but how would you take care of the ordering of the slides in a presentation? Or books in the authors list of books.

Comment: Use `order by` https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass?hl=en#Query_order Using the `book` example, you can sort the result by some criteria such as `publication_date`

Comment: The order should be controllable: a book should be able to move up and down in the author's list of books. This can be achieved with a `sort_value` property. But when you want to move a book around (by changing the `sort_value`) you have to update the `sort_value` for all the Author's books, which will need a query per book right?

Comment: I would suggest some sort of `music playlist` like construct to keep track of the ordering. You just need to be mindful of the 1Mb limit of an entity. I will update the answer to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

Your relationships are really the wrong way round. You should have a single KeyProperty on Book pointing at Author; then if you want to query all the books for a single author you can query on the Author key.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you check out the comments below Anthony's answer? The order is pretty important, that's why I modeled it this way around. So I can take advantage of the order in a repeated key property, which is a list.